# Extending an html5 dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, html

In the link bellow is the dropdown menu im using,the problem i have is that if i add more than six categories it messes up.Can i somehow hide the first six and extend a new menu?

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/comment-page-1/#comments

Comment: try change size this box, because now have 170px x 170px, you must change this in css and js.

Comment: i get what u saying if i resize the box indeed i will be able to put more boxes but the thing is i need like 22 of them so the only thought i had is to somehow hide first few boxes and have the next appear

Comment: ok so if you need 22 elements so you can set a ul width now in example is ul.sdt_menu{width:1020px} so example I create menu with 22 boxes and I set 6 box in a row. 170px * 6 = 1042px; this is my new width for a ul.sdt_menu. Now you can add another boxes to your menu but you must set margin bottom for li element so I use this: ul.sdt_menu li {margin-bottom:170px} why I use this value? because when you open menu you see sub menu so we need a space for this submenu, so I use for that margin bottom. For me this working so please try.

Comment: indeed this works thnks :D although it looks ugly with 22 elements :s im trying to somehow have them all in same line and by clicking an arrow expand the next row of elements figured that way it will look better.

Comment: i read on another answer that to hide menu items i sould set their CSS property to display: none; and place a button which targets these menu items and toggles their display property although i cant find working example.

Comment: you can use slider if you want create all boxes in one row, example 6 will be visible and if you want see another you must click on a arrow this is great example for you -> http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-an-infinite-jquery-carousel/

Comment: thnks so much thats exactly what i was looking for :)